# Keep javascript from being entered into a form or saved into database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

How would I keep javascript and php code from being entered into a form or saved to a database ? I'm still learning about client/server-side security and this seems to be an issue I need to resolve :p Could I do this on php side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inserting in a database with php, you can use the the strip_tags() function.

eg:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `DB` (`id`,`data`)
VALUES (".$id.",".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($data)).");";
$mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error().'<br/><pre>'.$query.'</pre>');//Debug only
```

The strip_tags function will strip all the html tags from the passed variable including the tag <script> so no JavaScript will be passed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

**Edit:**
Added the mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: If I were you, I would add mysql_real_escape_string before someone downvotes this. I've seen it happen to others.

Comment: can I strip specific tags? like only those with <script>

Comment: It had mysql_real_escap_string in it. But that is not the question. It's about stripping tags, passed by a form ... But well, i'll add it again ..

Comment: I've referred to this list several times to make sure I'm writing secure PHP code (as it's easy not to) - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-secure-apps/index.html

Comment: Yes you can, but the other way around. Instead of stripping, tags you can allow them like so: $striped_data=strip_tags($data,'<a><br><p>'); This will allow only the tags, a,br and p to NOT be stripped

Comment: what about htmlspecialcharacters?? that seems to work pretty well

Comment: You can use htmlspecialchars but you should know how that works. The function "translate" the characters like < and > and turn them into &lt; and &gt;. So when you get the content from the database and show it in a web page the browser will output < instead of &lt; . But if you need "translate" the special chars back and use the htmlspecialchars_decode() function, the data will be valid tags with javascript again.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote Could I do this on php side?

You have to - never (ever!) trust incoming data or clientside security checks via Javascript. Javascript can secure some content and take some workload off your server, but it is useless when bypassed or deactivated.

Use the Internet Search Engine of your choice, look-up and learn more about *SQL-injection* / *Cross Site Scripting (XSS)*.